# Save firebase background message locally in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, sqlite, firebase-cloud-messaging, sharedpreferences

Hi guys I'm working on app where I've to save FCM in mobile locally. It's working fine in foreground message but it's not working on background and terminate state.